# Is it possible to list all kernel symbols in memory?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to know if it is possible to list all the kernel symbols in a running linux kernel. I am aware that using nm I can always look at the symbols from a vmlinux image compiled without stripping the debug information.

Here is the scenario that I would like to use it:

- Write a kernel module to set timer interrupts and capture the return
  address
- Write controls to start/stop profiler
- Dump the data to a
  file and analyse it against the symbols from the currently running
  kernel

Challenges:

- Not having access to the vmlinux binary (I am currently running this on an embedded system without networking)
- I want to capture symbols from other loaded modules

Comment: Have you tried using `cat /proc/kallsyms`, which should list of the symbols. Additionally have you considered taking a vmcore for further analysis ?

Comment: `cat /proc/kallsyms` is a good idea. Thank you. I am not familiar with vmcore. As far as I understand it after taking a vmcore I cannot recover the running image right? Any debugging that I do must be done on the embedded system and it does not have networking or jtag.

Comment: Vmcore is a snapshot of the running image which will allows you to look into the data structures and symbols when the running kernel when the snap shot was taken, it a great way to narrow down issues.